# Session variable is not set when sending data to a php page using jQuery ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery which sends data on a button click using jQuery ajax() method, to a php page named 'follow_button'. The 'follow_button' page stores the data obtained from the jQuery, stores it in a variable, and then performs an insert to the database, along with the user id who clicked it. Now, the problem is, I need to extract the user_id of the user using the session variable. But under no circumstances, the page is able to extract the session variable. As a result of which the data sent is stored in the database, but the user_id is set to 0, since the session variable won't work. Here is the extract of the 'follow_button.php' page:
**follow_button.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
/* if(isset($_SESSION))
    echo "1.session set<br>";
else
    echo "1.session not set<br>"; */

include_once "includes/db.php";
include_once "includes/functions.php";
// include_once "includes/init.php";
// include_once "includes/insert_school_name.php";
/* if(isset($_SESSION))
    echo "2.session set<br>";
else
    echo "2.session not set<br>";


var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_POST); */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$id = get_id($email);
insert_school($id, $name);
?>
```

**Note:** The functions get_id() and insert_school() are working fine. Also it needs to be mentioned that the page which contains the button, is a wordpress page.
On success, the jQuery script changes the text of the button from 'follow' to 'following'. On button click, the text changes i.e., the call returns a success status. But when I check the database, the $name variable is inserted with the correct value, but the $id variable is inserted with the a value of 0.
Also the session variable works for all pages even the wordpress page containing the button. It just doesn't work for this specific page 'follow_button.php'.
How do I resolve this issue?
**Edit:** Added get_id() and insert_school() functions
**get_id()**:

```
function get_id($email) {
global $conn;

$sql = "SELECT id FROM member WHERE email = '$email'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

return $row["id"];
}
```

**insert_school()**:

```
function insert_school($id, $name) {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_schools (user_id, school_name)
    VALUES ('$id', '$name')";

    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: show us the code for `get_id()` and `insert_school()`

Comment: what sets session email?  I don't see anything that sets it

Comment: @Pete, it's set after a user successfully logs in. Don't worry about it, it's set for the rest of the part of the page, just isn't for this particular page referenced by the ajax() method